# Mule Schema validation when wsdl has embedded xsd

Tags: xsd, wsdl, mule

In Mule ESB I want to validate incoming SOAP/XML, using a standard Mule "schema-validation filter".

Something like:

```
<mulexml:schema-validation-filter schemaLocations="xxx.xsd" name="xxxValidationFilter"/>
```

However this kind of definition seem to assume that the schema is located in a separate xsd-file, whereas in a lot of cases the schema definition is embedded in the "wsdl:types" element of a wsdl-file.

Is there any way to use the Mule schema-validation-filter to validate against schema's which are embedded in the wsdl (except for copying the schema element definitions out of the
wsdl and into a separate xsd-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mule service element tags which expose the service haave an attribute that can enable validation on the incoming request.

```
validationEnabled="true"

<cxf:simple-service validationEnabled="true"/>
<cxf:jaxws-service validationEnabled="true"/>
<cxf:proxy-service validationEnabled="true"/>
```

For more information refer to the following Mule documentation link.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Building+Web+Services+with+CXF

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would that work, how would you define which schema to validate against in this case?

Comment: I did test this now, and found that with the 'validationEnabled' attribute enabled, the service is able to validate the request towards the schema embedded in the wsdl, so the suggestion did help, thanks! It remains as a question though, if it's possible to such validation by using the schema-validation-filter

Comment: If someone could explain the pros and cons, and functional difference between these two different validation apporaches, that would be great

Comment: For me these are two different approaches Mule is handling the validation based on the two different ways schema are handled in Web-services. Pros and Cons depends on the way you want to handle your schema in WSDL.